# Flutter: protocols, do they exist?

Tags: dart, flutter, protocols

I can't find a way to create a `Swift` protocol in **Flutter**. Do they exist or are there other replacement ways?

Comment: I don't know, in Swift I always called them protocols.

Comment: A link would help. Not everybody worked with protocols yet and your question doesn't contain the word Swift.

Comment: I checked the docs https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html briefly but it doesn't provide much information. Perhaps it's what is known from other languages (Java, C#, ...) as interface. Dart doesn't have a distinct interface concept. In Dart a class can implement the public interface of any other class. So `abstract class MyInterface { /* member declarations here */}` would do.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that there were also in other languages. My bad. And thanks for help

Comment: It's always a good idea to present a concrete problem you want to solve and allow the readers of the question do the abstraction how it could be solved in the target language/framework themselves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Dart you just create an `abstract class` and put all the methods you want its children to override. You can also provide an implementation:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  
  void method1(); // children must implement this method
   
  void method2() { // this method already has an implementation
    print("Just a print");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: But you can't inherit from multiple abstract classes

Answer (score 2):

In 2020, you are looking for `mixin` [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins)

This is almost like a protocol in Swift, it even enables you to add function implementations.

If link does not work, seems like it does work when copy-pasted, please google dart mixin.

Comment: Major difference I find between mixin and swift protocols is that mixins expect properties to be initialized